# How do you change the color of the initial text in a text field using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, text, textfield

And how do you make the text disappear when you click into the field and reappear when you click out of it?

Comment: Consider making these separate questions.

Comment: Note: you should make the text disappear ONLY if it's the default text, not the text the user has already begun typing! (in the case the user type the first half then do sth else and come back focusing again in the input text or in the case the user focus again to correct a typo before submitting its entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
input.placeholder {
    color:#ccc;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var placeholders = document.getElementsByClassName('placeholder');
    for(var p = 0; p < placeholders.length; p++) {
       var placeholder = placeholders[p];
       placeholder.onfocus = function() {
          this.value = '';
          this.removeClass('placeholder');
       };
       placeholder.onblur = function() {
          if(this.value == '') {
             this.addClass('placeholder');
          }
       }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The [color](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp) css property is used to set the text 
color.  You can use a name value, rgb value, or hex value.

Changing the visibility of elements in reaction to events will required some javascript knowledge.  You can use jQuery, which is a javascript library, to accomplish this.  By [toggling](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) behaviors, you could make an element disappear and then reappear.

If you're wanting something like having default text in the textbox until the user focuses on that, you'll need to handle the focus and blur events.  This [posting](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/default_text_fields_using_simple_jquery_trick.aspx) has a tutorial on this.

Comment: I tried using the color css property. I can't seem to change the text X within value="X" of the input tag though. How should I adapt my html code?

Answer (score 1):

do you just mean the color attribute for your first question? As for making the text disappear when you click into the field, do you mean an html input field?

If it is just a div, then setting an onmouseover and onmouseout event to hide the div (maybe use display:block and display:none) can accomplish that.

Comment: Yea, the color attribute a.k.a. the color of the text. In the input tag where you have value="X" I want to change the color of X. And yes, an html input field.